# Why does ioctl function with FIONREAD set argp parameter to 1 without any message?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, winsock, ioctl

```
int8_t RecvData(){

if (ioctlsocket(ServerSocket, FIONREAD, &sizebufferdata) != NO_ERROR)
{
    printf("Server: ioctlsocket reading failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ServerSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return(-1);
}

if (sizebufferdata != 0)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizebufferdata);
    char *ReceiveBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizebufferdata * sizeof(char));
    ReceivedDataLen = recvfrom(ServerSocket, ReceiveBuffer, sizebufferdata, 0, (struct sockaddr 
*)&ClientAddr, &ClientLen);

if (ReceivedDataLen == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Server: recvfrom failed with error %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
    free(ReceiveBuffer);
    closesocket(ServerSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return(-1);
    }
}
```

I'm constantly calling the RecvData() function and using non-blocking. When I send data from the UDP client, sizebufferdata returns the correct value. However, when I close the UDP client program, sizebufferdata incorrectly returns a value of 1. At the same time, the Recvfrom function works correctly by giving -1 on its return. 
Why does ioctl return  1 when UDP client closed?

Comment: You have a UDP connection. When the client closes the connection, exactly nothing happens on the network. So, a `recvfrom()`  would block waiting for data, not return `-1`. What is the error message you observe?

Comment: @Ctx In Ioctl function sizebufferdata is returned 1 when connection broken. I think it must be 0 or -1.

Comment: Did you close the UDP client program, or the UDP connection in the server ?

Comment: I closed UDP client program. I hoped return -1 or 0 in ioctlsocket(ServerSocket, FIONREAD, &sizebufferdata). But it was 1.